# mysql set value to empty if specific field is not empty

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have created this sql select query:

```
SELECT subscription_new_projects.banners, subscription_new_projects.banner_link
FROM subscription_new_projects
WHERE be_famous_id =32
AND now( ) < end_date
ORDER BY subscription_new_projects_id DESC
```

and getting this sql result:

[image]

Now I want to set `banners` field empty, If `banner_link` is not empty.

I want this result:

[image]

My SQL Fiddle: [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a9e1/3)

Any Idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case-when`

```
SELECT 
case 
when 
  subscription_new_projects.banner_link <> '' then '' 
  else subscription_new_projects.banners 
end as banners,  
subscription_new_projects.banner_link
FROM subscription_new_projects
WHERE be_famous_id =32
AND now( ) < end_date
ORDER BY subscription_new_projects_id DESC
```

Comment: Working perfect for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE`statement.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN subscription_new_projects.banner_link != ''
THEN NULL 
ELSE subscription_new_projects.banners
END AS banners,
subscription_new_projects.banner_link
FROM subscription_new_projects
WHERE be_famous_id =32
AND now( ) < end_date
ORDER BY subscription_new_projects_id DESC;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a9e1/8)